# Not able to use the advanced behavior config in gke cluster with the latest kubernetes version as well

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2 
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler 
metadata: 
  name: test 
spec: 
  behavior:
    scaleDown:
      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 0
      policies:
      - type: Percent
        value: 10
        periodSeconds: 15
    scaleUp:
      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 0
      policies:
              #-type: Percent
              #value: 100
              #periodSeconds: 15
      - type: Pods
        value: 5
        periodSeconds: 15
  maxReplicas: 30
  minReplicas: 2
  scaleTargetRef: 
    apiVersion: apps/v1 
    kind: Deployment 
    name: test
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 50
```

As per the Kubernetes official doc the HPA behavior is available for Kubernetes version v1.18 but GKE has it's own versioning. also it has api version "autoscaling/v2beta2" but the behavior is not supported.

GKE VERSION: **1.16.13-gke.1**

Am I the only one to face this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. GKE have it's own versioning. You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/versioning-and-upgrades).

> Note: The Kubernetes API is versioned separately from Kubernetes itself. Refer to the Kubernetes API documentation for information about Kubernetes API versioning.

Unfortunately, GKE is not supporting `behavior` parameter in `apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2`.

```
error: error validating "hpa.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(HorizontalPodAutoscaler.spec): unknown field "behavior" in io.k8s.api.autoscaling.v2beta2.HorizontalPodAutoscalerSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

However, it can be freely used with Kubeadm and Minikube with Kubernetes 1.18+.

There is already a [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166741876) related to this issue. You can add yourself to CC in this `PIT` to get new updates related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on GKE and facing issue where enabled API are

```
autoscaling/v1
autoscaling/v2beta1
```

while GKE version is around `1.12 to 1.14` you wont be able to apply manifest of `autoscaling/v2beta2` however you can apply same thing something like

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: core-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  maxReplicas: 9
  minReplicas: 5
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: core-deployment
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      targetAverageValue: 500m
```

if you want based on utilization

```
    apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
    kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
    metadata:
      name: core-deployment
      namespace: default
    spec:
      maxReplicas: 9
      minReplicas: 5
      scaleTargetRef:
        apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
        kind: Deployment
        name: core-deployment
      metrics:
      - type: Resource
        resource:
          name: cpu
          targetAverageUtilization: 80
```